# Correct form of escaping and localization - functions.php breadcrumbs

Tags: theme-development, escaping

I got this code for generating a WordPress breadcrumb online and want to make sure it's safe to use in a theme

```
<?php //// BREADCRUMB START ////       
 function the_breadcrumb() {

  $showOnHome = 0; // 1 - show breadcrumbs on the homepage, 0 - don't show
  $delimiter = '&raquo;'; // delimiter between crumbs
  $home = 'Home'; // text for the 'Home' link
  $showCurrent = 1; // 1 - show current post/page title in breadcrumbs, 0 - don't show
  $before = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
  $after = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb

  global $post;
  $homeLink = get_bloginfo('url');

  if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

    if ($showOnHome == 1) echo '<div id="crumbs"><a href="' . $homeLink . '">' . $home . '</a></div>';

  } else {

    echo '<div id="crumbs"><a href="' . $homeLink . '">' . $home . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';

    if ( is_category() ) {
      $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
      if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo get_category_parents($thisCat->parent, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
      echo $before . 'Archive by category "' . single_cat_title('', false) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
      echo $before . 'Search results for "' . get_search_query() . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo '<a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
      echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
        echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
        if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        if ($showCurrent == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)\s$delimiter\s$#", "$1", $cats);
        echo $cats;
        if ($showCurrent == 1) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
      $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
      echo $before . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
      $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
      $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
      echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($parent) . '">' . $parent->post_title . '</a>';
      if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
      if ($showCurrent == 1) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
      $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
      $breadcrumbs = array();
      while ($parent_id) {
        $page = get_page($parent_id);
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
        $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
      }
      $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
        echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
        if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      }
      if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
      echo $before . 'Posts tagged "' . single_tag_title('', false) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
       global $author;
      $userdata = get_userdata($author);
      echo $before . 'Articles posted by ' . $userdata->display_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
      echo $before . 'Error 404' . $after;
    }

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
      echo __('Page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
    }

    echo '</div>';

  }
} // end the_breadcrumb()

//// BREADCRUMB END ////
?>
```

My first concern:

```
  $homeLink = get_bloginfo('url');

  if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

    if ($showOnHome == 1) echo '<div id="crumbs"><a href="' . $homeLink . '">' . $home . '</a></div>';

  }
```

2. Should `esc_url` be used here :

   ```
     $homeLink = esc_url(get_bloginfo('url'));

     if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

       if ($showOnHome == 1) echo '<div id="crumbs"><a href="' . $homeLink . '">' . $home . '</a></div>';

     }
   ```

Or should it be used where I call for `$homelink`

3. Do I need to escape `get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);` here:

   ```
   if ( is_category() ) {
     $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
     if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo get_category_parents($thisCat->parent, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
     echo $before . 'Archive by category "' . single_cat_title('', false) . '"' . $after;

   }
   ```
4. Or should I just escape the last output like

   ```
   <?php if ( function_exists( 'the_breadcrumb' ) ) esc_html(the_breadcrumb()); ?>
   ```

5.. Regarding localization, I believe all such strings must be translate ready:

Archive by category should be `_e('Archive by category', 'theme-slug')`

Is that correct?

Updated function with escaping:

```
<?php //// BREADCRUMB START ////      
     function the_breadcrumb() {

     $showOnHome = 0; // 1 - show breadcrumbs on the homepage, 0 - don't show
      $delimiter = '&raquo;'; // delimiter between crumbs
      $home = __('Home', 'theme-slug'); // text for the 'Home' link
  $showCurrent = 1; // 1 - show current post/page title in breadcrumbs, 0 - don't show
  $before = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
  $after = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb

  global $post;
  $homeLink = get_bloginfo('url');

  if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

    if ($showOnHome == 1) echo '<div id="crumbs"><a href="' . esc_url($homeLink) . '">' . $home . '</a></div>';

  } else {

    echo '<div id="crumbs"><a href="' . esc_url($homeLink) . '">' . $home . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';

    if ( is_category() ) {
      $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
      if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo esc_html(get_category_parents($thisCat->parent, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' '));
      echo $before . __('Archive by category "', 'theme-slug') . esc_html(single_cat_title('', false)) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
      echo $before . __('You Searched for "', 'theme-slug') . esc_html(get_search_query()) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo '<a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
      echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url($homeLink) . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
        if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . esc_html(get_the_title()) . $after;
      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        if ($showCurrent == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)\s$delimiter\s$#", "$1", $cats);
        echo $cats;
        if ($showCurrent == 1) echo $before . esc_html(get_the_title()) . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
      $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
      echo $before . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
      $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
      $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
      echo esc_html(get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' '));
      echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink($parent)) . '">' . $parent->post_title . '</a>';
      if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . esc_html(get_the_title()) . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
      if ($showCurrent == 1) echo $before . esc_html(get_the_title()) . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
      $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
      $breadcrumbs = array();
      while ($parent_id) {
        $page = get_page($parent_id);
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
        $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
      }
      $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
        echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
        if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      }
      if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . esc_html(get_the_title()) . $after;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
      echo $before . __('Posts tagged "', 'theme-slug' ) . esc_html(single_tag_title('', false)) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
       global $author;
      $userdata = get_userdata($author);
      echo $before . __('Articles posted by', 'theme-slug' ) . $userdata->display_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
      echo $before . __('Error 404', 'theme-slug' ) . $after;
    }

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
      echo __('Page', 'theme-slug') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
    }

    echo '</div>';

  }
} // end the_breadcrumb()

//// BREADCRUMB END ////
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that you should escape *as close to the place of actual output as possible*. The reason for that is that if your escape is far removed from output then you assume output to be escaped... Until at some point in the future something changes in the other corner of the file and that’s no longer the case.

On what *should* be escaped is mostly matter of how likely it is to contain unsafe and/or user–produced input. Template tags are rarely explicitly escaped. In some cases escaping them would actively break stuff if they are *intended* to have HTML in the output under some circumstances. Like infamous admins being able to put HTML into titles.

Notably you can't HTML escape a whole block of HTML like a breadcrumb. Defeats the point.

You seem to be ok on localization bit.

Comment: So I'll need to escape `  $homeLink` in case 2, ` $thisCat`  in case 3  and there is no point of escaping in case 5. Is that correct?

Comment: In (3) I would escape stuff within output string, in (3) `$thisCat` is an object, can't escape that, probably won't escape template tags (not sure without look up), (5) hm, on second thought I _would_ escape arbitrary translated string in many circumstances, there is `esc_html__e()` or something like that.

Comment: Just tried escaping them all inside the function and html is totally messed up now.

Comment: That's the thing about escaping — there are no blanket rules. Everything has to be escaped _appropriately_ to where data is coming from, how safe it's considered to be, and what _kind_ of data it is.

Comment: I have now updated the escaped code block.